# Finding algebraic integer having a non-real conjugate $\beta$ with smaller absolute value and $\beta^n$ is real

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I have a math model and I would like to find some algebraic parameters which shows periodic behavior when raising powers. The problem is:

Given two positive real numbers $L\geq\ell\geq1$, can we construct an algebraic integer $\alpha$ satisfying the following properties:

- $\alpha$ is a real number and $\alpha\geq L$
- $\alpha$ has an algebraic conjugate $\beta$ with $\ell\geq|\beta|\geq1$
- $\beta$ is not a real number, but $\beta^n$ is a real number for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So the last property is that $\arg\beta$ is a rational number times $\pi$, and the condition $L\geq\ell$ forbids examples like $\alpha = 13^{1/3}$.

Can we have an algorithm or examples for e.g. $(L, \ell) = (3, 2)$ and arbitrary $(L, \ell)$?

Comment: $\beta^2=n-\sqrt{n^2+1}$.

Comment: And $K=\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ then $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$ is impossible for most $\ell$ because $O_K \cap \Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Z}$, so it remains to check $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=3$, then $\Bbb{Q}(\beta^n)$ is a strict subfield so $\beta^n\in \Bbb{Z}$ thus $\beta=\zeta_3 a^{1/3} b$ which doesn't work for most $\ell$ . @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ell=1$ then $\beta$ is a root of unity so $\alpha=\pm 1$. Otherwise

$$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},\qquad \phi^* = \frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}=-\phi^{-1}$$
Take $k$ odd large enough and $m$ chosen such that
$$\phi^{k/2}> L, \qquad m\phi^{-k/2}\in (1,\ell) $$
Let $$\alpha = m\phi^{k/2}, \qquad \beta = i m\phi^{-k/2} = m(\phi^*)^{k/2}$$